# Do I need /app/src/debug folder in my git after android run?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

After I changed icon of my app and run it, /app/src/debug folder was created.

Do I need it in git?
If not, why gitignore doesn't have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the build folder in git. You can delete it.

Additionally, don't forget to update your gitignore file.

- Make changes in .gitignore file.
- Run git rm -r --cached . command.
- Run git add . command
- git commit -m "Commit message" or just git
  commit or continue working.

Sample gitignore - android file.

```
# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Log/OS Files
*.log

# Android Studio generated files and folders
captures/
.externalNativeBuild/
.cxx/
*.apk
output.json

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/
misc.xml
deploymentTargetDropDown.xml
render.experimental.xml

# Keystore files
*.jks
*.keystore

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
google-services.json

# Android Profiling
*.hprof
```

The **debug** folder will need to be used if there is content in the relevant variant.

Comment: thx. I remembered I did mess some xml. Like changed launcher.xml in debug version or smth. 

I've del debug and it's fine. It doesn't create debug folder anymore.